# Adding styles and scripts to ASP.NET web controls (ascx) without repeating inclusion directives

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, stylesheet, web-controls

Consider to develop a web control (ASP.NET). What you would really like to do is styling and developing this control in a very good way, here's a very good way to do this (this is how I would like to do, further in this question I will explain why I cannot do this).

### A programmatic approach

1) I create my control in a separate folder called `WebControls` and I name it (for example) `MyWebControl`. I will have these files: `MyWebControl.ascx` and `MyWebControl.ascx.cs`.

2) Given that my control is a complex control I associate a style and a dynamic client behavior referencing, in the control html, a css stylesheet called `MyWebControl.ascx.css` and a javascript file called `MyWebControl.ascx.js`.

3) In my control I do the following:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" 
            AutoEventWireup="true" 
            CodeFile="MyWebControl.ascx.cs" 
            Inherits="MyApp.WebControls.MyWebControl" %>

<link href="MyWebControl.ascx.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="MyWebControl.ascx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div>
...
</div>
```

This is it!

### The problem

Well there is a problem in this thing: when my control is rendered, and in a page there is more than one of this control of mine, I get the links to the css and js file duplicated or even repeated more than once.

How to link an external stylesheet/javascript file in my control without occurring in this bad stuff?

### EDIT

OK, after looking a bit, with the help of others here in the community, I could understand that `Page.ClientScript` is what comes to the rescue.

However, there are a lot of functionality for a script to be registered... can you tell the difference among these?

1) `Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered`

2) `Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered`

3) `Page.ClientScript.IsOnSubmitStatementRegistered`

4) `Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered`

And the corresponding set methods?

1) `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`

2) `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude`

3) `Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement`

4) `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

Furthermore: can this be applied to javascript and css too?

Thankyou

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thought: wouldn't it be possible to use [ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) to inject the css-file import?

Something like(not tested):

```
if(! Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("MyWebControl.ascx.css"))
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.getType(),"MyWebControl.ascx.css",@"<style type=""text/css"" src=""MyWebControl.ascx.css""></style>");
}
```

*Edited to change `RegisterStartupScript` to `RegisterClientScriptBlock`*

According to your edits:

- RegisterStartupScript(type, key, script)
- RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, key, script)

The difference between these two methods is where each one emits the script block. `RegisterClientScriptBlock()` emits the script block at the beginning of the Web Form (right after the  tag), while `RegisterStartupScript()` emits the script block at the end of the Web Form (right before the  tag).

To better understand why there are two different methods for emitting client-side script, realize that client-side script can be partitioned into two classes: code that is designed to run immediately when the page is loaded, and code that is designed to run when some client-side event occurs. A common example of code that is designed to run when the page is loaded is client-side code designed to set the focus to a textbox. For example, when you visit Google, a small bit of client-side code is executed when the page is loaded to automatically set the focus to the search textbox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx#aspnet-injectclientsidesc_topic2

**Edit**: from your comments i'm assuming that it unfortuately does not work this way. Have a look at following links:

- http://forums.asp.net/t/557140.aspx/1?CSS+stylesheet+in+ascx+file/?post=2692177
- http://nathanaeljones.com/146/referencing-stylesheets-scripts-from-content-pages/

There might be some working approaches

As a hint, you could create the HtmlLink programmatically in Page_Init-Handler of your UserControl:

```
Dim objLink As New HtmlLink();
objLink.ID = "MyWebControlascxcss";
objLink.Attributes("rel") = "stylesheet";
objLink.Attributes("type") = "text/css";
objLink.Href ="~/filname.css";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(objLink);
```

You should remember to check first with a recursive function if the link was already added to `Page.Header.Controls-`Collection.

Comment: OK Tim, IT is obsolete, it is necessary to use the Page.ClientScript, see my edits because my question now turns into this one...

Comment: @Tim: Well I didn't try it... Visual Studio gave me such a bad notification for obsolete element usage ahahah :) however I think that the right way is using the ClientScript which handles specificcaly these issues. However thankyou, without you I could haven't find the elements now shown in the edit section of my question.

Comment: @Tim: Does it work with css and javascript???? By msdn, I found it but your description is a lot better, it seems that only javascript is supported.

Comment: @As i've mentioned before, it was only an idea. Have you tried but it does not work?

Comment: @Tim: with javascript works, but it is not good for CSS... Well, it seems that there is not a functionality to apple a stylesheet and include it in the page.....

Comment: @Andry: have a look at my posted links, there might be some working approaches, posted also an example.

Comment: @Tim Yes, in the end it is not possible... gotta manually insert the style... however I think this is not a good thing... Microsoft sgould work a bit on this :). Tim you were really helpful thankyou for your time and patience :)